# Biztalk 2013 - unconstructed message showing up only when i add the Exception handler

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-orchestrations

I working on building a simple connection with MS CRM. I am getting this 'Unconstructed message' error only when I add the Exception handler. I referred to another link [Use of unconstructed message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781482/use-of-unconstructed-message) - which tells that compiler might not be sure of the message being constructed before it is handled.

But I am creating the message in a map(Transform shape) - does that not guarantees that a message is created?

Do I need to add a message assignment shape before the transform and initialize the Request message?

Answer (score 1):

If you are constructing the message inside of the scope to which you have added the exception shape, then that message will be treated as Unconstructed as the exception may occur before or while the transformation occurs.

So no, the transform shape does not guarantee that the message will be constructed at all times.

Usually in this case you are better of using in your exception block the message that is on the initiating receive of your orchestration, or if you are trying to catch an exception after the transformation add a scope that starts after the transform shape and add an exception block to that.